# Deducing big numbers are prime using prime factors.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

*Hi, sorry I am a bit lost in my number theory homework and my notes do not contain anything on this topic. I would be grateful for a hint at how to start this question. Thank you.*

> Let p be a prime, and let q be a prime factor of $2^p - 1$
>
> Prove that $\operatorname{ord}_q(2)$ = p, and deduce that q $\equiv$ 1 (mod p).

Hence show, by hand, that $2^{13} - 1$ and $2^{17} - 1$ are both prime, and find prime factors of each of $2^{23} - 1$ and $2^{29} - 1$ .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll given you some hints:

(a) To show that $ord_{q}(2)=p$, you need to argue that $p$ is the smallest such that 
$$q|(2^p-1)$$
which should be straightforward from q is a prime factor of $2^p−1$.

(b) From Fermat's little theorem, since $q$ is a prime, $$q|2^{q-1}-1$$
and use part(a).

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to answer using this as a starting point. THANKS!

Comment: @teddyt55: You are welcome :)

Comment: I see how q being a prime factor of $2^p - 1 $ means q divides it, but does that imply that p is the smallest?

Comment: @teddyt55: Suppose there exists some integer $m$ with $1\leq m\leq p$ satisfying $m|2^p-1$. Then try to show that $m=p$ or 1.

Comment: do you mean $q|2^m-1$?

Comment: @teddyt55 oops i did mean $q|2^m−1$

Comment: Would I be correct in thinking that q|(2^p - 1), so 2^p=1 modulo q. Meaning that ord_q(2) divides p, so either ord_q(2)= 1 or p ?

Comment: @teddyt55: Yes, you are right.